# Can't pass an initial array to a useState to modify it later

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm pretty new in React Development. I want to pass several temperature values that come from props as initialState (via openWeather api), and then use the setTemperature to change with an onClick the values to their farenheit equivalent.

My code looks like this, and while the initial receives the values, the hook doesn't:

```
    const initialState = [tempCelsius, minTemp, maxTemp];
    const [temperature, setTemperature] = useState(initialState)

    const celToFar = () => {
        setTemperature((parseInt(initialState) * 9) / 5 + 32);
    };
```

I tried several other ideas, including this, which returns object object:

```
    const initialState = [tempCelsius, minTemp, maxTemp];
    const [temperature, setTemperature] = useState(prevState => {
    return {...prevState, initialState}
})

    const celToFar = () => {
        setTemperature((parseInt(initialState) * 9) / 5 + 32);
    };
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm pretty certain I don't need useEffect and should be able to do it if I pass the array correctly to the hook, since in console.log the function works when applied to individual props.

Comment: Could you please describe exactly what your hook should do? What arguments are passed to it and what it should return?

Comment: why do you need to save the props in state you can add the converting temperature function  in your parent and pass the converted temperature prop to your component and it will update OR you you can convert the temperature in you child and pass it to parent and pass the converted temperature as prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! :)

parseInt(initialState) will turn you array [1,2,3] to 1...

Change your function to this:

```
  const celToFar = () => {
      let farengeits = initialState.map(v => v * 9 / 5 + 32); 
        setTemperature(farengeits);
    };
```

To render values you can use:

```
 return (
    <div>{temperature.map((f, idx) => <div key={idx}>{f} F</div>}</div>
  )
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! now in the console.log I get the right values, so I need to figure how to replace the ones in my screen by these ones with the onClick.

Comment: @alha added example for render new values. Don't forget to accept answer if you think is right :)